# How to make a class or function uncallable in Python?

Tags: python

I want to make a class or function uncallable, so when the `callable` function is used on the function object/class object like `callable(function)` it will return `False`. I have already found out how to stop a class from being called and having instances by this:

```
class Object:
    def __new__(cls):
        raise TypeError('{} is not callable'.format(cls.__name__))
```

but then when I use `callable(Object)`, it still returns `True`. How do I make it uncallable and so then return `False` when the `callable` function is used on it?
even when I use

```
Object.__new__ = None
```

or

```
Object.__call__ = None
```

it still returns `False`

Comment: Please choose : a class OR a function not callable ? And for a class is it not instanciable ?

Comment: You can remove `__call__` as an attribute, but note, it would have to be removed from everywhere in it's MRO. This isn't practically possible (without hacking the runtime) for `function` objects because they are built-in objects

Comment: @MarcoEl-Korashy *methods are attributes*. But you are right, actually, because all class objects inherit from `type`, and you cannot remove `__call__` from `type` since it is a built-in (again, without serious, hacky solutions that would in this case almost certainl just break the interpreter). But you *can* remove `__call__` from, say, a user-defined callable class, e.g. `class Foo` with `__call__` defined, then just `del Foo.__call__`

Comment: So, `callable(Object)` is true because there exists a `Object.__call__`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I tried deleting my class' `__call__` attribute and then I declared it again to check if was deleted and it still came up and did not throw a `AttributeError`, so attributes for dunder methods cannot be deleted.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Also, I tried using `Object.__call__ = None` but `callable(Object)` still returned `True`

Comment: @MarcoEl-Korashy of course they can delete dunder methods from a class (as long as it isn't a built-in class). What *exactly* are you doing? But again, to make the *class* uncallable you don't do `del Object.__call__` you'd have to do `del type.__call__` so it doesn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't investigated exactly *why*, but it's difficult if not impossible to prevent an object of `<class 'type'>` from being callable. A workaround for this is to have an object *not* of that class, that acts exactly the same way in every other respect except being callable.

This can be done to a user-created class by using a decorator and a template `UncallableObject` class, which, given a template, copies the entire contents of that template's `__dict__` to itself, barring `__call__` (because we don't want it to be callable), `__dict__` (to avoid problems with recursion), and `__weakref__` (because python does not allow it).

```
def uncallable(f):
    class UncallableObject:
        def __init__(self, other):
            for k,v in other.__dict__.items():
                if k not in ('__call__', '__dict__', '__weakref__'):
                    setattr(self, k, v)
    g = UncallableObject(f)
    return g


@uncallable
class Object:
    pass
```

```
>>> @uncallable
... class Object: pass
... 
>>> callable(Object)
False
>>> Object()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'UncallableObject' object is not callable
>>>
>>> @uncallable
... def funnyfunc():
...   pass
... 
>>> callable(funnyfunc)
False
>>> funnyfunc()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'UncallableObject' object is not callable
```

In practice I see no practical reason to do this - using an [Abstract Base Class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) could probably fulfill whatever purpose you're trying to aim for, and would be easier to maintain. Whether or not an object should be called ought to be an issue of documentation, for the sake of clarity.

Comment: Is there a reason for having the `UncallableObject` class inside the function? Or just renaming it to `uncallable`.

Comment: There seems to be no point to using `class UncallableObject`... The problem with this approach though is that now your *class doesn't work like a class*. So try to define, say, `__len__` in `class Object` and it's not going to work

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy Thanks for your solution to my question, but how would I implement a uncallable class that cannot have instances with ABCs?

Comment: @MarcoEl-Korashy the answer to that probably depends on what you're using it for. Is there a particular reason you want `callable()` to return false for it, instead of just being content for it to throw a runtime error when you do try to call it?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy I want to make it uncallable because I don't want it to have new instances as I want it to be a singleton. (object without a class)

Comment: @MarcoEl-Korashy but that has *nothing to do with `callable` returning `False`*. If you want to make a singleton class, there are much better approaches than this, and what `callable` returns is irrelevant. More importantly, the above breaks because what you get is *not a class*. It wont' *work like a class at all*, and really you should just use something like `types.SimpleNamespace` instead if that's all you need

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible to make function objects or class objects uncallable from the perspective of `callable`, which basically just checks if the class has a `__call__` attribute. You can make a user-defined class uncallable that was defined as callable, e.g.:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __call__(self): return 'foo!'
...
>>> Foo()()
'foo!'
>>> callable(Foo())
True
>>> del Foo.__call__
>>> callable(Foo())
False
```

However, class objects all inherit from `type`, a built-in, and you cannot delete attributes from built-in classes:

```
>>> del type.__call__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'type'
```

And even if you hacked your way around it, it would break the interpreter, because it fundamentally relies on class objects being callable, and this would prevent **all classes** from being callable.

Perhaps there is some metaclass magic you can do to make a class object uncallable, but the attribute resolution in this scenario is a bit arcane... my naive attempts have failed. I thought maybe this might work:

```
>>> class Uncallable(type):
...     def __getattribute__(self, name):
...         print('getting', name)
...         if name == '__call__':
...             raise AttributeError
...         return super().__getattribute__(name)
...
>>> class Foo(metaclass=Uncallable): pass
...
>>> callable(Foo)
True
>>> Foo()
<__main__.Foo object at 0x7f830a892df0>
```

But it doesn't, because special methods (i.e. "dunder" methods) bypasses `__getattribute__`... maybe there is an obvious solution I'm not seeing...

Anyway, there are probably *much more sensible* workarounds. An uncallable class doesn't make a lot of sense anyway, what, *exactly* are you trying to actually accomplish?